# Django Dict Filter several AND OR Condition

Tags: django

i try to make a filterdict dynamicaly. As Result i get for example such a filterdict:

```
filterdict {'price_from__lte': Decimal('120000.00'), 'price_till__gte': Decimal('120000.00'), 'wc': True, 'balcony_count_from__lte': 1, 'balcony_count_till__gte': 1}
```

So i can filter searchcriterialist = Searchcriteria.objects.filter(**filterdict)

But i want from every field a OR Condition where all items with Null are include. So i need a dict like this:

```
filterdict {('price_from__lte': Decimal('120000.00') OR 'price_from__lte': NULL), ('price_till__gte': Decimal('120000.00') OR 'price_till': 0), ('wc': True OR 'wc': NULL), ('balcony_count_from__lte': 1 OR 'balcony_count_from':0), ('balcony_count_till__gte': 1 OR 'balcony_count_till':0)}
```

How can i build dynamical i dict with a mixture of OR and AND Contitions?

Regards

Comment: Why are some checks null and some zero? Do you really need both?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution with Q().

Thanks